# Node.js and Vue.js, why Refresh make vue.js's store clear? And how can i use uploaded image in vue.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, path, upload

Title is my questions.

**First.** I'm making simple diary app with Node.js and Vue.js. Vue-router using history mode and in backend, using "connect-history-api-fallback" module. I think i did everything i can do, but when i run my app in local, refresh make vue.js's store clear. I googled but can't find same problem. Someone have any idea?

**Second.** I'm using Multer to upload. Upload is fine, i can see uploaded image. But i don't know how to show that uploaded image.

I mean in vue's template, what path will show uploaded image?

Image uploaded here "/simple-diary/backend/upload/profilePhoto/"
Vue.js component is here "/simple-diary/frontend/src/components/"

Comment: One question per post. Also do you get this on local or prod servers? Are you using express for the backend?

Comment: In local, and using express for backend. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @samayo is right.One question per post.So of course when the page refresh the store is refreshed.So if you dont want that you can use plugin like vuex-persistedstate.Or if you want to keep the token and the user that is currently logged then when the user logged in,use localstorage to save the token and the user.Or cookies.Or session storage.You have many options

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will ask one question per post next time. I tried and it was nice. Thank you, again.